# Twig: replace arbitrary token in variable with template include

Tags: replace, symfony, template-engine, twig

I'm looking to replace tokens within variables passed to my template from a controller, with an include for another template; something conceptually like:

```
// controller
$post->content = "<p>Here's a short post that an enduser wrote. The enduser wants
    product info to appear here: %product_info_here%. Over and out.</p>";

// Twig template
<div class="content">
  {{ post.content
     | replace({ '%product_info_here%': include('product_info.html.twig') }) }}
</div>
```

From starting to look at the Twig code, it looks like filters do not have access to their context, and so would not be able to perform this. Does this functionality exist already, and if not, where would be the correct place in the twig architecture to add it?

**UPDATE:**

This is in order to enable the end user to determine where the app should inject the partial. My putting the example in the controller was for brevity; really the literal token will be part of a Post record in the database as entered by the end user, and the post content will be passed to the Twig template. I would like the Twig template to parse the post content for the token, and inject the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain a bit more as to why you would want to put templates in your controller?  I would think the following would work just as well:

```
// Twig template
<div class="content">
  <p>Here's a short post. Product info: {% include('product_info.html.twig') %}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok.  I don't know a straight forward way but you should be able to do this using an embedded controller passing post.content as an argument.